# Byte array (may contain special character) in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, base64

Decode a message (may contain special character) with base64 from Bash. Saving to file would yield 48 bytes of data. Yet if passing it to a variable, it became a 41 bytes of string. I believe this is caused by Bash's way of handling special characters (^@).

As an example,

```
meow_bash=`printf $variable | base64 --decode`
echo ${#meow_bash}  # return 41

printf $variable | base64 --decode > meow
wc -c meow # return 48
```

Now if I don't want to save the array to file due to the sensitive nature of data. I also need to use shell script to do it. Is there a way for me to use bash/sh to pass it successfully?

Comment: ^@ is a nul byte, and can't be stored as a bash variable or passed as an argument to any program. Don't use bash for binary data. You can store the base64 and convert it whenever you write it to something.

Comment: IIRC I've also seen bash (I think it was an old version) get confused by delete characters (hex 7f). And depending on the locale, some tools may refuse to deal with e.g. sequences that aren't valid UTF-8, and... Because of this, shell tools that deal in binary data will either take it in base64 (or hex or something similar), or via pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, learn to quote your expansions: use `printf "$variable"`, not <s>`printf $variable`</s>

The simplest cause of this is that c defines a variable as ending in a zero byte.
Therefore a c string could not contain a zero byte.
Bash (being written in c), silently removes any zero value inside **variables**.

But could work with zero bytes in streams (pipes and the like).

The simple workaround is to not store the values (after decoding) inside variables.

Also note that a variable may contain any byte value when stored encoded in base64.

Thus, the variable could be assigned the *safe* base64 encoded value:

Using the value of the variable in a pipe erase no byte:

```
$ variable="YWoAa2hzZ2RrAGxzawBmZGp2"
$ printf '%s' "$variable" | base64 --decode | wc -c
18
```

That is: an stream could contain zero value bytes.

But assigning the decoded value to a variable:

```
$ variable="YWoAa2hzZ2RrAGxzawBmZGp2"
$ meow_bash="$(printf '%s' "$variable" | base64 --decode)"
$ printf '%s' "$meow_bash" | wc -c
15
$ echo "${#meow_bash}"
15
```

The variable `$meow_bash` has lost 3 zero bytes.

Comment: I guess the take home message would be: don't ever assign any byte array directly to bash variable, no matter what...